# What do I have to do to get a Border Layout to have the West container full height of the viewport?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, border-layout

I am trying to use the `Border` layout in Extjs 4.2.1, when I specify `North` and `South` containers they expand and fill the entire horizontal space in the viewport, I want them to allow the `West` panel to be full height instead.

Here is some simple ASCII art version of what I am trying to achieve.

```
-----------------
|W|____North____|
|E|    Center   |
|S|_____________|
|T|    South    |
-----------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You can also use the weight property to give precedence to a
>   region—for example, giving precedence to the West region over the
>   North region. All these changes mean that you should not often need
>   nesting with border layout, speeding up rendering of components that
>   use that layout.

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainViewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'west',
                    weight: -1,
                    width: 150,
                    title: 'My Panel'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'north',
                    weight: -2,
                    height: 150,
                    title: 'My Panel'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'south',
                    weight: -2,
                    height: 150,
                    title: 'My Panel'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'east',
                    width: 150,
                    title: 'My Panel'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'center',
                    title: 'My Panel'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```